# View deployment history from the command line or PowerShell

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-cli

I am deploying through source control to a Microsoft Azure Website. It's a pain to log in to the Azure Portal and click through the UI to view the deployment history. Can we manage deployments from the command line or PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use both the PowerShell or xplat (commandline) tools to do this.

More about installing them here:

- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/xplat-cli/
- http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/install-configure-powershell/

For the xplat use:

```
azure config mode 'asm'
site deployment list [options] [name]
site deployment show [options] <commitId> [name]
site deployment redeploy [options] <commitId> [name]
site deployment github [options] [name]
```

For PowerShell:

```
Get-AzureWebsiteDeployment [[-CommitId] <String>] [[-MaxResults] <Int32>] [-Details] [[-Name] <String>] [-Slot <String>] [<CommonParameters>]`

Get-AzureWebsiteDeployment -Name mySite
```

Also you can browse to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net there you can also view your deployments using REST apis.

Answer (score 1):

**Azure CLI for Web Apps.** We find the legacy Azure Service Manager mode easiest for this. Also, we find the output more readable in JSON. Using `--max` limits the results.

```
azure config mode asm
azure site deployment list MySiteName --max 1 --json
```

**Azure CLI for Web App Slots.** We can also retrieve a specific `--slot`.

```
azure config mode asm
azure site deployment list MySiteName --slot MySlotName --max 1 --json
```